# Filter out the result after count() function

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-analysis, snowflake-schema

How can I filter out the result after using count() function on that column?
e.g. I am count the Id's, I want to filter out the ID that **only counted once**.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please provide the data structure, SQL you've already tried and the problem with the results. Have you tried using the HAVING clause: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/having.html

Comment: @AlexandreJuma Sorry I meant I want to get them not filtering them out :) my query look like this: SELECT count(Customer_ID) FROM orders -- I stopped here and I couldn't reach my goal which is getting only the IDs that was present only once in the ORDERS table :)

Comment: Please edit your question with those details... they should not be in the comments. Regarding the HAVING statement, it should allow for the logic you want.  Example: `SELECT a.id, COUNT(*) as CNT FROM docs a GROUP BY a.id HAVING COUNT(*) <> 1`

Comment: you need to provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

To get entire rows with filter applied for `Id` column, you could use `QUALIFY`:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Id) AS cnt
FROM tab
QUALIFY cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this over using a window function:

```
SELECT id, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM tab
GROUP BY id
HAVING cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

So both Lukasz and Mike's answer's are the two ways to get the ID's that present more that once, and Lukasz's being the way to get other columns (and avoid crazy big GROUP BY clauses). Albeit, the problem with his answer in the context, is a row that has ID present 5 times, will have 5 rows, in this pattern.

But given the comments (which should have been edited into the questions) you noted:

> I have:
>
> ```
> SELECT count(Customer_ID) FROM orders
> ```
>
> I stopped here and I couldn't reach my goal which is getting only the IDs that was present only once in the ORDERS table

if we ignore the SQL as it appears to be going the wrong way. But to get the `ORDER's` that are the only order for a customer, can be done like:

```
SELECT
    o.detail_a,
    o.detail_b,
    o.customer_id
FROM order AS o
QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_id) = 1;
```

or if you are wanting just the customer_id's where they have only a single order, which for example you might use in JOIN later (thus thus is the type of thing poked into a CTE)

```
SELECT 
    customer_id,
    COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM ordered
GROUP BY 1
HAVING cnt = 1;
```